# Dynamically changing PXSelector by event in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I have some problems with forming a dynamic selector, below I will imagine what has been done.
I need to dynamically generate a selector depending on the selected AssetId.
The AssedInfo selector must return information depending on the type of information selected in the AssetId. I tried, in steps:

```
public class NSIAssetLinkInfo: IBqlTable
    {
        #region AssetId
        [PXDBString(500, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Asset Id")]
        [PXStringList(
            new string[]
            {
                "AssedInfo","GLTran"
            },
            new string[]
            {
                "AssedInfo","GLTran"
            })]
        public virtual string AssetId { get; set; }
        public new abstract class assetId : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<assetId> { }
        #endregion

        #region AssetInfo
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Asset Information")]
        [PXDBString(500, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
        public virtual string AssetInfo { get; set; }
        public abstract class assetInfo : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<assetInfo> { }
        #endregion
    }
```

In here, I created a button and an event that should dynamically form our selector.
And it is also necessary that the event that the selector will form returns not all the columns, and only the necessary ones, for example, "AssetID - RecordType," if you are accurate, then you need only those columns that I will indicate, and not all.
[added button to panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQwR2.png)

```
public class KNRWAPInvoiceEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
    {

        public SelectFrom<GLTranR>.View GLTrans;
        public SelectFrom<FixedAsset>.View FXAsset;

        public SelectFrom<NSIAssetLinkInfo>.View NSIAssetLinkInfo;

      
        public PXAction<APInvoice> LinkInfo;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "LinkInfo", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Delete, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Delete)]
        protected void linkInfo()
        {
            if (TagPanel.AskExt(true) != WebDialogResult.OK) return;

            //Do some useful Stuff
        }

        public PXFilter<NSIAssetLinkInfo> TagPanel;


        public virtual void _(Events.FieldSelecting<NSIAssetLinkInfo, NSIAssetLinkInfo.assetId> e)
        {
            if (e.Row == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var assetId = e.Row.AssetId;
            

            if (assetId == "GLTran")
            {
                //gltran
                //saves TranID
                //Displays RefNbr - InventoryID
                //not all gltran, but gltran which has accountid
                var returnState = PXFieldState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, dataType: typeof(FixedAsset), isKey: false, nullable: null,
                    required: null, precision: null, length: null, defaultValue: null, fieldName: null);
                e.ReturnState = returnState;
                returnState.Visible = true;
                returnState.Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible;
                returnState.Enabled = true;
                returnState.DisplayName = "RefNbr";
                returnState.ViewName = "GLTrans";
                returnState.DescriptionName = "GLTranR";
                returnState.FieldList = new[] { nameof(FixedAsset.AssetID), nameof(FixedAsset.Description), nameof(FixedAsset.Depreciable) };
                returnState.HeaderList = new[]
                {
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<FixedAsset.assetID>(FXAsset.Cache),
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<FixedAsset.description>(FXAsset.Cache),
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<FixedAsset.depreciable>(FXAsset.Cache),
                };
            }
            if (assetId == "AssedInfo")
            {
                //Fixed Asset
                //saves InventoryID
                //InventoryID - Desc
                //not all fixed assets, but those, which has class 
                var returnState = PXFieldState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, dataType: typeof(GLTranR), isKey: false, nullable: null,
                    required: null, precision: null, length: null, defaultValue: null, fieldName: null);
                //descriptionName: null, displayName: null, error: null, errorLevel: PXErrorLevel.Undefined,
                //enabled: null, visible: null, readOnly: false, visibility: PXUIVisibility.Visible, viewName: null,
                //fieldList: null, headerList: null);
                e.ReturnState = returnState;
                returnState.Visible = true;
                returnState.Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible;
                returnState.Enabled = true;
                returnState.DisplayName = "RefNbr";
                returnState.ViewName = "GLTrans";
                returnState.DescriptionName = "GLTranR";
                returnState.FieldList = new[] { nameof(GLTranR.InventoryID), nameof(GLTranR.TranDesc), nameof(GLTranR.RefNbr), nameof(GLTranR.DebitAmt), nameof(GLTranR.CreditAmt) };
                returnState.HeaderList = new[]
                {
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<GLTranR.inventoryID>(GLTrans.Cache),
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<GLTranR.tranDesc>(GLTrans.Cache),
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<GLTranR.refNbr>(GLTrans.Cache),
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<GLTranR.debitAmt>(GLTrans.Cache),
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName<GLTranR.creditAmt>(GLTrans.Cache)
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Button in View

```
<CallbackCommands>
    <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="LinkInfo" Visible="false" />
</CallbackCommands>
```

And

```
<px:PXToolBarButton>
           <AutoCallBack Command="LinkInfo" Target="ds" />
</px:PXToolBarButton>
```

And

```
<px:PXSmartPanel ID="pnlCopyCompany" runat="server" CaptionVisible="True" Caption="My Command" Style="position: static" LoadOnDemand="True" Key="TagPanel" AutoCallBack-Target="frmMyCommand" AutoCallBack-Command="Refresh" DesignView="Content">
<px:PXFormView ID="frmMyCommand" runat="server" SkinID="Transparent" DataMember="TagPanel"  DataSourceID="ds" EmailingGraph="">
           <Template>
<px:PXGrid runat="server" SyncPosition="true" KeepPosition="true" Height="150px" SkinID="Details" Width="865px" Caption="Caption"
              CaptionVisible="false" MatrixMode="True" RepaintColumns="true"
DataSourceID="ds" AllowPaging="True" AdjustPageSize="Auto" NoteIndicator="false" FilesIndicator="false" Style='left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 188px;'>
              <AutoSize Enabled="True" MinHeight="200" />
                    <ActionBar PagerVisible="False" />
                    <CallbackCommands>
                        <Refresh CommitChanges="True" />
                    </CallbackCommands>
                    <Levels>
<px:PXGridLevel DataMember="NSIAssetLinkInfo" DataKeyNames="TagInfoID">
                            <RowTemplate>
                                <px:PXDropDown runat="server" ID="edAssetId" CommitChanges="True" DataField="AssetId" AllowMultiSelect="True" />
<px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="edAssetInfo" DataField="AssetInfo" AutoRefresh="True" CommitChanges="True" />
                            </RowTemplate>
                            <Columns>
                                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="AssetId" CommitChanges="True" />
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="AssetInfo" CommitChanges="True" />
                            </Columns>
                        </px:PXGridLevel>
                    </Levels>
                </px:PXGrid>
            </Template>
        </px:PXFormView>
</px:PXSmartPanel>
```

[I plan what would be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE2Vc.png)

Answer (score 2):

I am struggling to follow your example vs. what you are saying you need to do.  It looks like you are want to properly set the list of allowed values in AssetID as predefined list. This is much simpler than your example if you use the RowSelected event and predefine your allowed lists. Below is a very trimmed down example showing how I accomplish this with 1 sample list.  You can define multiple lists according to your allowed combinations and specify the desired type for listattr according to your conditions.

```
protected void _(Events.RowSelected<XXMyDAC> e)
{
    if(*condition*) // Substitute your conditional logic here
    {
        SelectableValues listattr = new SelectableValues();
        PXStringListAttribute.SetList<XXMyDAC.myField>
            (e.Cache, row, listattr.AllowedValues, listattr.AllowedLabels);
    }
}

public class SelectableValues : PXStringListAttribute
{

    public string[] AllowedLabels = new string[]
    {
            Messages.MyLabel1,
            Messages.MyLabel2
    };

    public string[] AllowedValues = new string[]
    {
            MyValue1,
            MyValue2
    };
}
```

If you need to limit values being returned from the database rather than from a predefined list, you would use PXRestrictorAttribute on the DAC field either directly in the DAC or via CacheAttached in the graph.  Here is a very simple example of that using a custom field called UsrXXMyCondition added to INLocation (via the DAC extension INLocationExt).

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(
    Where<INLocationExt.usrXXMyCondition, NotEqual<ConditionType.condition1>>
    ), "")]
protected virtual void INTran_ToLocationID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```